# Updating Error in Pop-OS

Tags: pop-os

I don't have any technical knowledge of linux terminal.

This problem arised recently while I was trying to update my Pop-OS(22.04):

[image]

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that you're not allowed to access Microsoft's server.

My guess would be that your proxy blocks you. Or your computer's IP block is completely prohibited from accessing microsoft servers, as happens, for example, to servers and countries caught as being part in hacking attacks.

Comment: uhmm I was able to use it for few updates and it didn't show that problem but now it's showing that .

Comment: so , how do I solve this

Comment: you literally can't. It's microsoft's server locking you out.

Comment: uhmm,so  how do I  remove this from showing in my terminal

Comment: You remove the line specifying the microsoft server from /etc/apt/sources.list or the file containing it in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

Comment: uhmm how do i do that . can u explain in answer section.
it would be great help from u if  u do it

Comment: no. How to edit a text file is not something I need to explain. *You* tried to install VS Code because you wanted to program, so I trust you know how to edit text files.

Comment: how do u know I tried to install vs code

Comment: I recommend actually reading the error messages you get…

Comment: uhmm actually the problem is gone now on its own , idk how it happened but i am grateful for ur help